# how to sort the legends horizontally in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

The common legends can be:

```
-a  -d
-b  -e
-c  -f
```

which is sorted vertically. While how to sort the legends horizontally?
for example:

```
-a  -b
-c  -d
-e  -f
```